# NotificationListenerService stops after some time and never restart again

Tags: android, service

I know it is a known issue mention here https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=63793 and https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=62811.
I just want to know is there any alternative way to restart my NotificationListenerService when it stops from the background.

Manifest `<service
        android:name=".activity.services.NotificationService"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:permission="android.permission.BIND_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SERVICE">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.service.notification.NotificationListenerService"/>
      </intent-filter>
    </service>`

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. Make the service class, and register in the manifest like you did.

Here is the code for your class. Don't forget to make it Foreground:

```
class NotificationService extends NotificationListenerService {
    public void onNotificationPosted(StatusBarNotification sbn) {
        String pack = sbn.getPackageName();
        sbn.getId();
        Model model = new Model();

        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(mPreviousNotificationkey)|| !TextUtils.isEmpty(mPreviousNotificationkey)&& ! sbn.getKey().equals(mPreviousNotificationkey)) {
            mPreviousNotificationkey =sbn.getKey();
            String ticker = "";

            if (sbn.getNotification().tickerText != null) {
                ticker = sbn.getNotification().tickerText.toString();
            }

            Bundle extras = sbn.getNotification().extras;
            String title = extras.getString(NotificationCompat.EXTRA_TITLE.toString());
            String text = extras.getString(NotificationCompat.EXTRA_TEXT.toString());
            extras.getString(NotificationCompat.EXTRA_SUB_TEXT.toString());
            long time = sbn.getPostTime();
            int etra_small_icon = extras.getInt(Notification.EXTRA_SMALL_ICON);
            Bitmap large_icon = sbn.getNotification().largeIcon;
            Intent msgrcv = new Intent("Mymessage");
            // you can use here log.
            msgrcv.putExtra("package", pack);
            msgrcv.putExtra("ticker", ticker);
            msgrcv.putExtra("title", title);
            msgrcv.putExtra("text", text);
     }

 }
```

Comment: Hi bro, I'm getting a problem with that, always the service stop and I don't know what more can I do? can you help me with this problem. Thanks